# OpenGL - vertices/triangles not rendered

Tags: c++, opengl

So I've been trying to learn OpenGL lately, following several text and video tutorials.

I cant get the triangle to draw, I've double and triple checked that I'm preforming all the necessary steps in the right order, but I'm obviously missing something

before adding some of the code I should state that im using glfw, glad and ogl 4.6.

Main.cpp

```
//while debugging ive add extra unnecessary call to UseProgram and bindvertexarray every frame to be sure
static void Render(GLFWwindow* window)
{
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
    gladLoadGLLoader((GLADloadproc)glfwGetProcAddress);
    glfwSwapInterval(1);
    glClearColor(.98f, .5f, .5f, 1);

    std::vector<Vertex> vertsTri = {
        {
            Vertex(0.0f,1.0f,0.0f,0,0,0,0,0)
        },
        {
            Vertex(-1.0f,-1.0f,0.0f,0,0,0,0,0)
        },
        {
            Vertex(1.0f,-1.0f,0.0f,0,0,0,0,0)
        }
    };
    Model tri(vertsTri, "basic");
    tri.UseProgram();
    glBindVertexArray(tri.getVAO());

    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        // rendering here
        tri.UseProgram();
        glBindVertexArray(tri.getVAO());
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, tri.size());

        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
    }
}

int main()
{
    glfwSetErrorCallback(errorCallback);
    if (!glfwInit())
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 4);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 6);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);

    GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(800, 600, "Title", nullptr, nullptr);
    if (!window)
    {
        glfwTerminate();
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    glfwSetFramebufferSizeCallback(window, windowResizeCallback);
    glfwSetKeyCallback(window, keyCallback);

    // Resource loading and creation in here


    std::thread renderThread(Render, window);

    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
        // Realtime game mechanics here


        glfwPollEvents();
    }

    if (renderThread.joinable())
        renderThread.join();

    glfwDestroyWindow(window);

    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}
```

Model.cpp

```
//Gets called in the constructor with a Vertex vector, p_shader is created in Model constructor
void Model::Create()
{
    // Generate a vertex array object and bind it
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &p_vaoId);
    glBindVertexArray(p_vaoId);
    // Generate a vertex buffer object and bind it
    glGenBuffers(1, &p_vboId);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, p_vboId);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, p_vertices.size()*sizeof(Vertex), &(p_vertices[0]), GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    // Define attributes and enable them
    glEnableVertexArrayAttrib(p_vaoId, 0);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, sizeof(Vertex::position) / sizeof(float), GL_FLOAT, false, sizeof(Vertex::position), (void*)offsetof(Vertex, position));
    glEnableVertexArrayAttrib(p_vaoId, 1);
    glVertexAttribPointer(1, sizeof(Vertex::normal) / sizeof(float), GL_FLOAT, false, sizeof(Vertex::normal), (void*)offsetof(Vertex, normal));
    glEnableVertexArrayAttrib(p_vaoId, 2);
    glVertexAttribPointer(2, sizeof(Vertex::uv) / sizeof(float), GL_FLOAT, false, sizeof(Vertex::uv), (void*)offsetof(Vertex, uv));
}
```

Shader.cpp

```
// p_v/fShaderSource is set in LoadSource, while debugging ive made sure the source is gotten correctly
void Shader::Create()
{
    int errorResult = 0;

    // Load shader sources into memory before anything else
    LoadSource();

    // Creating shader objects
    p_vShaderId = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    p_fShaderId = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);

    // Compile the shaders
    Compile(p_vShaderId, p_vShaderSource);
    Compile(p_fShaderId, p_fShaderSource);

    // Create a program object
    p_programId = glCreateProgram();

    // Attach shaders to the program
    glAttachShader(p_programId, p_vShaderId);
    glAttachShader(p_programId, p_fShaderId);

    //Link the program and handle errors
    glLinkProgram(p_programId);
    glGetProgramiv(p_programId, GL_LINK_STATUS, &errorResult);
    if (!errorResult)
    {
        int length;
        glGetShaderiv(p_programId, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &length);
        char* log = new char[length];
        glGetProgramInfoLog(p_programId, length, &length, log);
        std::cout << "[Link Error] Failed to link program" << std::endl;
        std::cout << log << std::endl;
        delete log;
        glDeleteShader(p_vShaderId);
        glDeleteShader(p_fShaderId);
    }

    // Validate the program and handle errors
    glValidateProgram(p_programId);
    glGetProgramiv(p_programId, GL_VALIDATE_STATUS, &errorResult);
    if (!errorResult)
    {
        int length;
        glGetShaderiv(p_programId, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &length);
        char* log = new char[length];
        glGetProgramInfoLog(p_programId, length, &length, log);
        std::cout << "[Validate Error] Failed to validate program" << std::endl;
        std::cout << log << std::endl;
        delete log;
        glDeleteShader(p_vShaderId);
        glDeleteShader(p_fShaderId);
        glDeleteProgram(p_programId);
    }

    // Cleanup shaders after linking and validating
    glDetachShader(p_programId, p_vShaderId);
    glDetachShader(p_programId, p_fShaderId);
    glDeleteShader(p_vShaderId);
    glDeleteShader(p_fShaderId);
}

void Shader::Compile(unsigned int& shaderId, std::string source)
{
    int compileResult = 0;
    const char* csource = (const char*)source.c_str();
    glShaderSource(shaderId, 1, &csource, 0);
    glCompileShader(shaderId);
    glGetShaderiv(shaderId, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &compileResult);
    if (!compileResult)
    {
        int length;
        glGetShaderiv(shaderId, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &length);
        char* log = new char[length];
        glGetShaderInfoLog(shaderId, length, &length, log);
        std::cout << "[Compile Error] Failed to compile shader - \"" + source + "\""<<  std::endl;
        std::cout << log << std::endl;
        delete log;
    }
}
```

basic.vert

```
#version 460 core

layout(location = 0) in vec3 position;
out vec4 fColor;

void main()
{
    gl_Position.xyz = position;
    gl_Position.w = 1.0;
    fColor = vec4(gl_Position.xyz, 1.0);
}
```

basic.frag

```
#version 460 core

in vec4 fColor;

layout(location = 0) out vec4 diffuseColor;

void main()
{
    diffuseColor = vec4(1,0,0,0);
}
```

I've removed some of the class specific code that doesnt perform any ogl calls,
if that make it too hard to diagnose i could add the entire code, as its not too bad.
I've tried multiple styles of out color in the fragment shader and non of the ones ive tried have worked, with that said though, let me know if you believe that problem is indeed in the fragment shader.

Comment: yes, why is that a problem? the context is reset to the render thread before anything happens there, and from my understanding its possible to render on a different thread ( ive done it in sfml which uses ogl )

Comment: I did make the context current though, and it did clear with the glClear. also ive just revised it to render on the main thread and the results were sadly the same.

Comment: That use of `sizeof` operators in the glVertexAttribPointer parameters looks odd.

Comment: indeed the problem was in vertexattrib, specifically the stride was wrong, should have been sizeof(Vertex) and not sizeof(Vertex::attrib) - thank you

Answer (score 1):

pointed by @datemwolf:
problem was with the stride parameter that was passed to glVertexAttribPointer

From:

```
glVertexAttribPointer(0, sizeof(Vertex::position) / sizeof(float), GL_FLOAT, false, sizeof(Vertex::position), (void*)offsetof(Vertex, position));
glVertexAttribPointer(1, sizeof(Vertex::normal) / sizeof(float), GL_FLOAT, false, sizeof(Vertex::normal), (void*)offsetof(Vertex, normal));
glVertexAttribPointer(2, sizeof(Vertex::uv) / sizeof(float), GL_FLOAT, false, sizeof(Vertex::uv), (void*)offsetof(Vertex, uv));
```

To:

```
glVertexAttribPointer(0, sizeof(Vertex::position) / sizeof(float), GL_FLOAT, false, sizeof(Vertex), (void*)offsetof(Vertex, position));
glVertexAttribPointer(1, sizeof(Vertex::normal) / sizeof(float), GL_FLOAT, false, sizeof(Vertex), (void*)offsetof(Vertex, normal));
glVertexAttribPointer(2, sizeof(Vertex::uv) / sizeof(float), GL_FLOAT, false, sizeof(Vertex), (void*)offsetof(Vertex, uv));
```